# Passing props though Link component of React Router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am creating a login/signup page using React Router. I have created a single page for login/signup, inside that single component I am using conditional rendering to show the login and signup parts. I have created two buttons on the navbar  and want to set props so that on clicking on login  I will get the login part and on signup, I will get the signup part. Unable to figure out how to pass props in <Link>.

Route defined:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    errorElement: <Error />,
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "auth",
        element: <Authentication />, // this is the login/signup route
      },
      {
        path: "/forget-password",
        element: <ForgetPassword />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```

Navbar (where the <Link> tg is present):

```
<Link to="/auth" className={classes.btn}>
          Get Started
</Link>
<Link to="/auth" className={classes.btn}>
          Login Up
</Link>
```

Here I want to pass props ("login" and "signup" in the Link tags)

Authentication component (where conditional rendering is happening):

```
function Authentication({ setMode }) {
  const [authMode, setAuthMode] = useState("login");

  return (
    <section className={classes.container}>
      <div>
        <img src={auth} alt="" />
      </div>
      <div>
        {authMode === "login" ? (
          <Login setAuthMode={setAuthMode} />
        ) : (
          <Signup setAuthMode={setAuthMode} />
        )}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<Link>` component does not except props that are passed to the later component.

There are multiple ways to fix this, but how about including it in the URL? That also makes it clear for the user on what page he/she currently is.

```
<Link to="/auth/sign-up" className={classes.btn}>
    Get Started
</Link>
<Link to="/auth/login" className={classes.btn}>
    Login Up
</Link>
```

And then change the router like so:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    errorElement: <Error />,
    element: <Root />,
    children: [
      {
        index: true,
        element: <Home />,
      },
      {
        path: "auth",
        children: [
            { path: "login", element: <Authentication mode={'login'} /> },
            { path: "sign-up", element: <Authentication mode={'sign-up'} /> },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: "/forget-password",
        element: <ForgetPassword />,
      },
    ],
  },
]);
```